# Orchard field mediapicker field placement

Tags: orchardcms

I created a ContentType (named Trainer) using the interface and used a media picker field to input the trainer's photo besides a text field for trainer's current position and 2 parts(Title and Body) to define other info.

When browse the trainers and go to the details of the trainer the photo appears at the end of all other fields and I cannot find howto use placement.info to have the photo be displayed on top of all the fields and other parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the default rules in Orchard.MediaLibrary:

```
<Match DisplayType="Detail">
    <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker="Content:after"/>
</Match>

<Match DisplayType="Summary">
    <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker_Summary="-"/>
</Match>

<Match DisplayType="SummaryAdmin">
    <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker_SummaryAdmin="Content:after"/>
</Match>
```

So in your case it would be:

```
<Match ContentType="Trainer">
    <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker="Content:before" />
</Match>
```

Or, when you might add multiple medialibrarypicker fields in the trainer content type:

```
<Match ContentType="Trainer">
    <!-- Photo is the name of your field in this case -->
    <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker-Photo="Content:before" />
</Match>
```

Enable the shape tracing module to easily find out how to target the field:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info

Comment: Thanks devqon. To hide the Image title and the metadata I had to use smth like:

<Match ContentType="Image">
    <Place Parts_Common_Metadata_Summary="-"/>
    <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-"/>
    <Place Parts_Title_Summary="-"/>
  </Match>

This will match many other things. So I used smth like this but no success. What am I missing?

<Match ContentType="Egitmen" DisplayType="Detail">
    <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker ="Content:before" />
     <Match ContentType="Image">
         ... same rules as above
     </Match>
  </Match>